# Which event fires when a vb.net form lost focus?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Which event is fired when a VB.NET form loses its focus? I am using Krypton Navigator.

```vb
Me.kryNavi.Pages.Add(kryPage)
With pform
    .TopLevel = False
    .Parent = kryPage
    .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    .BringToFront()
    .Show()
    .Activate()
End With
```

I am using the above code to show a form.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Form.Deactivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event. It "occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form."

Comment: Thanks, It Works well when not using Krypton Navigator Control.